# Sales prediction with neural networks

Tags: machine-learning

How is a time series like the Rossmann Kaggle competition used to forecast sales? The simplest solution  I saw is a random forest. There the data for every time point is used to feed the random forests. So there is no time dependence because I use every data at each time as independent. Thats also good. But what I a doing if I want to solve this with a neural network?

So my input layer corresponds to every time point (for the same time independence)?

In the data mining Cup 2017 there is a similiar competition. there are over 5000 products with attributes like if it was clicked or drawn to the basket or ordered.

Since there are intreractions between the user actions like clicking at the product, history come important.

Do I have to train a neural network for each product to forecast revenue?

Answer (score 0):

You can either work with a neural network and add chunks of data to its input layer. This could work, and it's taking the time dependency in some sort of way but not in the cleanest way (in my opinion). If it is a time-series, what I would do is use a [recurrent neural network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrent_neural_network), either a [LSTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory), or a [GRU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gated_recurrent_unit), even a Simple RNN could work. In the end, a simple RNN is just a Neural network with layers for each timestep, meaning that if you unfold the recurrence of the RNN it will produce a normal feedforward neural network with more than one hidden layer (depending on the number of timesteps). Also, remember that in a neural network we do not know how the network came up with the decision (it's a black box) so either model should work just fine.

If you are going to use a RNN, I would train a neural network for each store for example, or make the inputs of all the stores into the input layer (depending on what you want to do). The output layer would be either one store's forecast (1 neuron in the output layer) or the forecast for each of the stores (n neurons in the output layer).

A good way of knowing what to do is to train, test, validate and compare approaches. Try both the NN and the RNN to see which one works better in this scenario, change number of layers, change number of inputs, number of outputs, etc. To my understanding there is no fixed solution when using neural networks.

Hope this helps to get you going on your research.

Comment: I would add that in the specific case of the Rossman competition, a large percentage of the shops had missing data for an extended time period (something like 6 months out of 2 years training data). Those shops required predictions same as the others. This made constructing time-series data for the whole data set somewhat harder.

Comment: @NeilSlater you are right, how to handle missing data is always a challenge.